# How to upload a file to a local folder with React.js and Node.js?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have tried this php and html file upload:
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

and I was wondering If the same could be done using React.js/Nodes.js.
I'm not really used to coding and have never worked with React.js before.

Comment: The same can absolutely be done with NodeJS. You don't even really need React. This question is generally too broad to be answered. Keep searching in the same general direction though, what you're trying to do is very possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can split that up into to parts:
The backend part which is done in Node.js. Therefore you can use something like [ExpressJS](http://expressjs.com/) as framework. Add a POST route and handle your file upload.

The second part would be React. React has nothing to do with the backend system. It's only used to build GUIs. It's a combination of fancy HTML and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

If you are wondering about the complexity of handling this process, here is a snippet of code that uses the formidable package to handle a file upload in Node.JS

```
  /** UPLOAD a file **/
  app.post('/upload', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
    // create an incoming form object
    var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

    // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
    form.multiples = true;

    // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
    form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '../../uploads');

    // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
    // rename it to it's orignal name
    form.on('file', function(field, file) {
      logger.info(`Uploaded: "${file.name}"`);
      fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
    });

    // log any errors that occur
    form.on('error', function(err) {
      errorLogger.error('During file upload: ' + err);
    });

    // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
    form.on('end', function() {
      res.end('success');
    });

    // parse the incoming request containing the form data
    form.parse(req);
  });
```

My particular client-side implementation didn't use React, just a plain HTML/Javascript page using the jQuery [Dropzone](http://www.dropzonejs.com/) plugin but I see that React has uploader packages as well like '[react-dropzone](https://react-dropzone.netlify.com/)'.

[Here](https://github.com/coligo-io/file-uploader) is the link back to the complete example repository that accomplishes file uploads in node.js  Checkout the upload.js file to view how the client-side file streaming is done to the node server.

Comment: And how do I connect this to:
<input type="file" name="upload" />
<input type="submit" value="submit" > ?
sorry for asking a lot, since I don't know much about coding

Comment: I added a link back to a complete example of doing a file upload in node.js  I would suggest looking through that code to see the full client/server working scenario.